# Dbeaver hive cannot see the result of select. it shows -1 rows updpated. no results

Tags: database, select, hive, dbeaver

I have beeen recently working on metadata of hive database from dbeaver. i cant query them at all. whatever i query the script is executed but i cant see the results. it shows the query executed but i cant see any results only stats are opened.Please help me.